# Como pegar o nome de dia da semana do primeiro dia do mês?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data

Como faço para pegar o nome (segunda, terça, quarta...) do primeiro dia do mês de dezembro a partir da data atual?

Comment: Acho que sua pergunta tá meio confusa.. pra mim, o primeiro dia do mês é sempre dia 1 :P

Comment: @rLinhares, quero o nome do dia (segunda, terça, quarta..) primeiro dia do mês de dezembro

Comment: @vnbrs, editei a pergunta

Comment: desculpas @vnbrs, fiz lá

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode utilizar o [`FORMAT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) também. Veja:

```
DECLARE @Data DATETIME = '2017-12-01 00:00:00'
SELECT FORMAT(@Data, 'dddd') AS dia_semana
```

O retorno:

```
dia_semana
-------------
Friday
```

O formato `dddd` é referente ao dia da semana. O `DATENAME`, citado na resposta do [@MarconcilioSouza](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/246808/nome-do-primeiro-dia-do-m%C3%AAs/246815#246815) pode ser utilizado para obter o nome do mês e do ano também. O formato que utilizei é para obter o dia da semana e somente.

- [MSDN: Date and Time Data Types and Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql)
- [MSDN: `FORMAT` (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)
- [MSDN: `DATENAME` (Transct-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql)

Answer (score 6):

Se você já sabe a data por usar o:

```
SELECT DAYNAME('2017-10-16');
```

Caso precise da data em português e seu banco não tiver configurado pode usar antes da query assim:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';
```

Só toma cuida pois se user o SET vai ter que voltar para a linguagem padrão depois que retornar a query.

Comment: editei a pergunta.

Comment: Neste caso você pode pegar o ano corrente assim:

select year(now());

Comment: Nao entendo pq o pessoal faz mil códigos, e tao simples fazer isso! Essa devia ser a resposta aceita!

Answer (score 4):

Se quiser deixar o mês flexível, pode deixa-lo em uma variável a parte, segue o exemplo:

```
declare @mes varchar(2) = '12'
select DATENAME(weekday, '2017-' + @mes + '-01') as dia_semana
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode montar a query da seguinte forma.

```
SELECT (DATENAME(dw, CAST('12' AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST('1' AS VARCHAR)  + '/'  + CAST(DATEPART(yy, getdate()) AS VARCHAR)) )
```

Comment: esse script ta trazendo somente no mes atual, mas quero trazer dessa mesma forma, mas do mes de dezembro

Comment: @RenanBessa, veja que estou manipulando a data o mês esta no primeiro `CAST('12' AS VARCHAR)`

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, editei a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso também pode usar assim:

```
SET @var := year(now());
Select @var, DAYNAME(CONCAT_WS('-', @var,'12-01'));
```

Comment: Isso se fosse MySQL

Comment: Qual banco está usando ?

Comment: esta na tag da pergunta.

Comment: Não prestei atenção, desculpa. Vou fazer no SQL. Obrigado.